# How can i get the ip address of the computer that running a react-native project on?

Tags: node.js, react-native

Right now i'm developing an app with React-Native and .NET Core on macos. I travel with my computer a lot and my computers local ip address changes and so my WebAPI url accordingly. I don't want to apply these changes to my react-native project manually everytime my ip changes, i want to make a service that can get my computers ip address so i can make my API Url more generic.

I tried

```
react-native-network-info
```

but apparently this gives the ip address of the mobile device, so it's not useful for me.